# Обработка POST запросов в Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Перебрал уже весь интернет, но не нашел данной информации. В общем у меня Arduino посылает post запросы на сайт с показателями и датчиков, построенный на Django. Как мне обработать эти запросы и добавить их в базу данных?В основном нужна помощь с написанием представления. Прошу, опишите подробнее решение данной задачи, ибо я новичок в этой теме

Comment: Не важно, `POST` это или `GET`, принцип один и описан в каждом учебнике. Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос. Вам не получается создать представление? Или проблема с моделями? Вы хотя бы раз работали с `Django`?

Comment: В Django я конкретный новичок, но основы +- понимаю. Как я понял, мне нужно во view написать функцию, которая будет принимать и обрабатывать http запрос с Arduino, после чего добавлять все это в БД. Ссылаюсь на post запросы, поскольку я с Arduino шлю запросы подобного типа.

Comment: Да, всё просто. `Arduino` тут вообще, кстати, ни при чём. Если она посылает стандартные `HTTP` запросы, то воспринимайте её просто как любой другой клиент.

Comment: Буду невероятно благодарен, если поможете

Comment: Полезнее всего будет вернуться к основам, освоить фреймворк в первую очередь и овладеть базовыми навыками. Советую найти на ютубе скринкасты по запросу "пишем приложение на django с нуля" или что-то вроде, пройти их полностью, на время забыв про свое приложение. Почитайте документацию https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/, если английский не на уровне, можно воспользоваться переводчиком сайтов, вставив ссылку сверху на странице здесь https://translate.yandex.ru/translate

Comment: Понимаете, я имею понимание, как работать с Django. Если бы мне нужен был ответ на вопрос по поводу работы с допустим БД, то я вы не обращался на форумы. Мне нужна помощь с написанием представления, по которому я не нашел нормальной инфы

Comment: @12 в документации нормальная инфа есть: [раз](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/), [два](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/)

Comment: Не могу понять, почему так тяжело помочь человеку, если по вашим словам дело минут на 10